# Python - Multiple json profiles with thread?

Tags: python, json, multithreading

So basically my plan for today was to create multiply profiles from json and make them run as a thread. The problem is that I have never done threading but I have read about it and it doesn't feel that complicated but as a first try and also a advice for this could be really useful for me to make something like this possible.

However what I was thinking is to have a json file looking like this:

```
[{
    "Name": "Baller",
    "Lastname": "cavs",
    "Email": "baller@gmail.com"
},
{
    "Name": "Lakers",
    "Lastname": "Nation",
    "Email": "baller@gmail.com"
}
```

]

which I hope is correct validated by Json at this moment.

So basically with the json file is that every profile made there should run into a thread that makes the logic into my script but at this moment I just have

```
  {
        "Name": "Baller",
        "Lastname": "cavs",
        "Email": "baller@gmail.com"
    }
```

which only allow once and if I add [ ] to make multiple tasks, I will get a error because it doesn't know what [] are doing...
but how do I need to do/think to make it run on a multiple json tasks and to make them run into a thread (I assume thread is the best to go?). What I want it to do is that make each profile into a thread. Do the same logical code in my script/code and then yes.. End when its done pretty much.

Please feel free to comment. I will also edit this by the time I get further!

---

EDIT:

```
  {
    "Profiles": {
        "profile1": {
            "Name": "Baller",
            "Lastname": "cavs",
            "Email": "baller@gmail.com"
        },
        "profile2": {
            "Name": "Lakers",
            "Lastname": "Nation",
            "Email": "baller@gmail.com"
        }
    }
}
```

I have changed my Json file into that and what code I have been trying to do is:

```
with open('profile.json', 'r', encoding='UTF-8') as json_data:
    config = json.load(json_data)

Name = config["Name"]
print(Name)
```

but i'm getting a error saying `KeyError: 'Name'`

I assume it couldn't find it at all?.. So here i am.. I think what needs to be done is maybe a loop through profiles? But then im thinking like if I do a loop then it will just run 1 by 1 and not all of the profiles at the same time?

Comment: Can you provide some code which you maybe already tried ?

Comment: Yes. I will edit now the result I have done

Comment: @YaroslavSurzhikov There you go

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You get KeyError, because name is not in dictionary. Try get profile with `config['Profiles']['profile1']['Name']` for example. And your first solution with list should work too if you iterate over the elements in it.

assuming your JSON looks like:

```
[ {profile1}, {profile2}, etc ]
```

Your code would be:

```
with open('profile.json', 'r', encoding='UTF-8') as json_data:
    config = json.load(json_data)

for profile in config:
    Name = profile["Name"]
    print(Name)
```

On edited json example:

```
with open('profile.json', 'r', encoding='UTF-8') as json_data:
    config = json.load(json_data)

for profile_cfg in config['Profiles'].values():
    Name = profile_cfg["Name"]
    print(Name)
```

Comment: Oh okey. so the question is. Is it gonna run like each profile for each other? Like first the profile 1 and then profile 2? In that case. If I want them to run at the same time. I assume I need to use the thread then? @Yaroslav

Comment: But also if iam reading it correct. That means that if I have a code we say etc 300 lines. I need to make all of it in dented block to make it work as a loop, Don't I? @YaroslavSurzhikov

Comment: No, you dont, because you can wrap your code in class or function or even into module and execute it with threading/multipricessing from that loop. As for first question - if you use list of dictionaries - it will. But if you using dictionary of dictionaties - its not ( dictionaries are unordered in python )

Comment: Yeah. Currently I do not have anything at this moment with Thread and Mutiprocessing but I might think of it. Currently I tried the code you gave exemple but it didnt go profile by profile. Or that it does each profile and excute the code I have written for each profile.. If i remember right it wont notice which profile to start so it assume the last one.